# Scala function to count specific occurrences

Tags: scala, function, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have the below spark data frame:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0bXj.png)

What I am trying to do is create a scala function/UDF which would give me the column "Longest Run". This will show me greatest number of countries a passenger has been in without being in the UK. For example, the first one is : uk -> ir -> at -> uk -> ch -> pk , the correct answer would be 2 countries here.

I have attempted to create a function but it doesn't work if I have multiple "uk" in a list or the list begins with "uk".

How would I go about this please?

Thank you for your support

Answer (score 0):

You could try this approach

```scala
  def longestRun(sq: Seq[String]): Int = {
    sq.mkString(" ")
      .split("UK")
      .filter(_.nonEmpty)
      .map(_.trim)
      .map(s => s.split(" ").length)
      .max
  }

  case class Flights(passengerID: Int, flight: Seq[String], longestRun: Int)

  val data = List(
    (1,List("UK","IR","AT","UK","CH", "PK")),
    (2,List("CG","IR")),
    (3,List("CG","IR","SG","BE","UK")),
    (4,List("CG","IR","NO","UK","SG","UK","IR","TJ","AT")),
    (5,List("CG","IR"))
  )

    import spark.implicits._

    val df = sc.parallelize(data)
      .toDF("passengerID", "Flight")
      .map(r => Flights(r(0).asInstanceOf[Int],r(1).asInstanceOf[Seq[String]],longestRun(r(1).asInstanceOf[Seq[String]])))
    
    df.show(truncate = false)

/*
+-----------+------------------------------------+----------+
|passengerID|flight                              |longestRun|
+-----------+------------------------------------+----------+
|1          |[UK, IR, AT, UK, CH, PK]            |2         |
|2          |[CG, IR]                            |2         |
|3          |[CG, IR, SG, BE, UK]                |4         |
|4          |[CG, IR, NO, UK, SG, UK, IR, TJ, AT]|3         |
|5          |[CG, IR]                            |2         |
+-----------+------------------------------------+----------+
*/
```