# Create a list of lists from two columns in a data frame - Scala

Tags: arrays, list, scala, apache-spark

I have a data frame where passengerId and path are Strings. The path represents the flight path of the passenger so passenger 10096 started in country CO and traveled to country BM. I need to find out the longest amount of flights each passenger has without traveling to the UK.

```
+-----------+--------------------+
|passengerId|                path|
+-----------+--------------------+
|      10096|               co,bm|
|      10351|               pk,uk|
|      10436|   co,co,cn,tj,us,ir|
|       1090|   dk,tj,jo,jo,ch,cn|
|      11078|         pk,no,fr,no|
|      11332|sg,cn,co,bm,sg,jo...|
|      11563|us,sg,th,cn,il,uk...|
|       1159|      ca,cl,il,sg,il|
|      11722|      dk,dk,pk,sg,cn|
|      11888|au,se,ca,tj,th,be...|
|      12394|            dk,nl,th|
|      12529|            no,be,au|
|      12847|               cn,cg|
|      13192|      cn,tk,cg,uk,uk|
|      13282|         co,us,iq,iq|
|      13442|   cn,pk,jo,us,ch,cg|
|      13610|   be,ar,tj,no,ch,no|
|      13772|            be,at,iq|
|      13865|         be,th,cn,il|
|      14157|               sg,dk|
+-----------+--------------------+
```

I need to get it like this.

```
val data = List(
(1,List("UK","IR","AT","UK","CH","PK")),
(2,List("CG","IR")),
(3,List("CG","IR","SG","BE","UK")),
(4,List("CG","IR","NO","UK","SG","UK","IR","TJ","AT")),
(5,List("CG","IR"))
```

I'm trying to use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64462784/scala-function-to-count-specific-occurrences) but I can't make this list of lists. It also seems like the input used in the solution has each country code as a separate item in the list, while my path column has the country codes listed as a single element to describe the flight path.

Comment: Hello and welcome :) Please share any attempts you've made on this, this will help others to provide specific answers by updating your code.

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is just to generate the list of destinations from a string, you can simply use `split`:

```scala
df.withColumn("path", split('path, ","))
```

If the goal is to compute the maximum number of steps without going to the UK, you could do something like this:

```scala
df
    // split the string on 'uk' and generate one row per sub journey
    .withColumn("path", explode(split('path, ",?uk,?")))
    // compute the size of each sub journey
    .withColumn("path_size", size(split('path, ",")))
    // retrieve the longest one
    .groupBy("passengerId")
    .agg(max('path_size) as "max_path_size")
```